# Order by on array before pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="creations accordion" ng-repeat="creation in filteredCreations | orderBy : field : reverse">
   [[creation.id]]
   [[creation.name]]
</div>
```

And angular controller:

```
var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp', ['ui.bootstrap']).config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');
});

exampleApp.controller('CreationController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.currentPage = 1;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 2;

    creations = $.map(creations, function(value, index) {
        return [value];
    });
    $scope.creations = creations;
    $scope.filteredCreations = [];

    $scope.order = function(field) {
      $scope.reverse = ($scope.field === field) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
      $scope.field = field;
    };
    $scope.field = 'id';
    $scope.reverse = false;

    $scope.figureOutCreationsToDisplay = function() {
        var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage)
        , end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;

        $scope.filteredCreations = $scope.creations.slice(begin, end);
    };

    $scope.figureOutCreationsToDisplay();

    $scope.pageChanged = function() {
        $scope.figureOutCreationsToDisplay();
    };
}]);
```

So I paginate the results each time the page changes, and then display the paginated result. Which means orderBy filter sorts the data ONLY on paginated set, not all results.

And I want to sort all data and then paginate it.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do the orderBy in the controller, prior to the list being rendered. Then if you have any trigger that changes the orderby order, you will just have to call the sort function in controller. Here is a link to how you can leverage angular orderBy in the controller (so you don't have to write your own).

```
$scope.filteredCreations = $filter('orderBy')(itemsArray, "field")
```

http://sravi-kiran.blogspot.com/2013/12/InvokingAngularJsFiltersFromController.html